# Cursor android sms - how to get countryISO

Tags: android, cursor, sms

I have this code where i read all the informations about sms:

```
Uri mSmssentQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
Cursor cursorS = getContentResolver().query(mSmssentQueryUri,null, null, null, null);
if (cursorS.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cursorS.moveToNext()){
        date = cursorS.getString(4);
        address = cursorS.getString(2);
        JSONObject jsonSms= new JSONObject();
        jsonSms.put("type", "sms");
        jsonSms.put("date", date);
        jsonSms.put("receiver", address);
        jsonSms.put("direction", "OUTGOING");

        jsonObj.put("SMS"+date, jsonSms);
    }
}
```

I do the same thing with the calls where i use the CallLog.calls but i can find more informations like countryIso that it gives me the country code of the country where the user received or made the call.
Is there a way to get the same information when i send sms, so i can read that the sms was sent from abroad?

Comment: see DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor

Comment: I did and i get these infos: "_id, thread_id,address,person,date,protocol,read,status,type,reply_path_present,subject,body,service_center,locked,error_code,seen". Nothing related with country

Answer (score 0):

pass address field value as phone in  below function

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    // phone must begin with '+'
    PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phone, "");
    int countryCode = numberProto.getCountryCode();
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```